# Rails: How to authenticate user on mobile native with Devise+Omni-facebook+Devise_token_auth after obtaining the access token

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth-facebook

How do I use facebook access token on Devise + Omniauth-facebook + Devise_token_auth?

Is there a way to hook the access token into the omniauth-facebook somehow and get the user signed up/logged in? Or any other solution is welcome.

I am able to obtain the access token from facebook graph API on my mobile side.

I've tried to place the access token on the callback url as such:
/omniauth/facebook/callback?code=ACCESS_TOKEN
but it simply returns
{"errors":["Use POST /sign_in to sign in. GET is not supported."]}

I have looked at:

[Rails API: Authenticate users from native mobile apps using username/password or facebook token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995448/rails-api-authenticate-users-from-native-mobile-apps-using-username-password-or)

Suggested solution to look at Warden, but I don't think it needs to be so complicated.

[omniauth for rails and ios authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908836/omniauth-for-rails-and-ios-authentication)

Suggested solution is a gem, but the gem is no longer maintained.

[Rails Devise OmniAuth Facebook Login from iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663740/rails-devise-omniauth-facebook-login-from-ios)

Suggested solution affected mobile side development, which I'm hoping not to.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try something and it seems to work.

I've taken codes from @JeremyMoyers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995448/rails-api-authenticate-users-from-native-mobile-apps-using-username-password-or). It's really an ad-hoc solution but it seems to do the trick.

I've overwritten DeviseTokenAuth controller action for omniauth_success:

Routes:

```
config/routes.rb

namespace :api do
  scope :v1 do
    # mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
    mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
      omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks',
      }
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

class OmniauthCallbacksController < DeviseTokenAuth::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def omniauth_success
  # get_resource_from_auth_hash
  # Remove original get_resource_from_auth_hash and implement custom get_resource
  get_resource_from_uhash(params[:access_token],params[:expires_in])
  create_token_info
  set_token_on_resource
  create_auth_params

  # Skip confirmation is done at custom get_resource
  # if resource_class.devise_modules.include?(:confirmable)
  # don't send confirmation email!!!
  # @resource.skip_confirmation!
  # end

  sign_in(:user, @resource, store: false, bypass: false)

  if @resource.save!
    update_auth_header
    yield @resource if block_given?

    redirect_to @resource
    # render_data_or_redirect('deliverCredentials', @auth_params.as_json, @resource.as_json)
  else
    redirect_to rooth_path
  end
  end

protected
  def get_resource_from_uhash(access_token, expires_in)
  graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
  profile = graph.get_object('me?fields=email,name,id,picture')
  # logger.info(profile)
  @resource = User.where({
    uid:      profile['id'],
    provider: 'facebook'
    }).first_or_initialize do |user|
      user.provider = 'facebook'
      user.uid = profile['id']
      user.name = profile['name']
      user.oauth_token = access_token
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.image = profile['picture'] if profile['picture'].present?
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(expires_in)
      user.skip_confirmation!
      user.save!
    end

  if @resource.new_record?
    @oauth_registration = true
    set_random_password
  end
  @resource
  end
end
```

Let me know if there are any security concerns for this.